# How to remove spaces between a string and an argument when using the print statement in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a variable var1. Suppose `var1 = 10` , then how can I print `"$10"` ? I tried `print("$",var1)` but the returns `"$ 10"`. I don't want the space in the middle. This implementation is for Python3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendation is to use format strings with [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). You can print it like this

```
print("${}".format(var1))
```

Here, the value of `var1` will be substituted inplace of `{}`, at runtime. Alternatively, you can do simple string concatenation, like this

```
print("$" + str(var1))
```

The string concatenation works only with string types. So, you need to convert the `var1` from integer to string with `str` function. Otherwise, you will get the following error

```
print("$" + var1)
# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print("$", var1, sep='')
```

Would also do the job